# how to use wysiwyg-editor?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

please help to solve the problem.

I'm trying to use wysiwyg-Editor:
https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.fields import HTMLField

class News(models.Model):                       
    text = models.HTMLField(
        'Основной текст',
        max_length=50000, 
        blank=False,
    )
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
   )
```

when trying to use the command:

```
python manage.py schemamigration app_news --auto

I get the following error message:
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik5/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik5/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 128, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik5/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kalinins/.virtualenvs/blogik5/blogik5/settings.py", line 149, in <module>
    mod = import_module(app)
NameError: name 'import_module' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't seem to have anything to do with wsyiwyg-editor: you are calling `import_module(app)` in your settings.py file, but have not defined or imported that function in that file.